# Excel VBA that calls Powershell ActiveDirectory cmdlet, but Module won't load?

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, vba, macros, active-directory

I have a powershell script I use to dump user and computer lists to csv files; it works great and I don't want to touch it much.  It uses the ActiveDirectory cmdlet, and the Get-ADComputer and Get-ADUser cmdlets.

I've used vb excel (2007) macros that call powershell scripts before.  Example:

```
Sub test()
'
' test Macro
'
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    PSCommand1 = "Import-Module ActiveDirectory; "
    objShell.Run "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command """ & PSCommand1 & """", 1, True
'
End Sub
```

Now, I specifically reference the import-module command there because there's one difference between powershell VBA and powershell outside of vba...the ActiveDirectory module cannot be found.  If I add -noexit to the powershell invoking command to leave the shell open after the command fails, I can type:

```
get-module -ListAvailable
```

And the ActiveDirectory module isn't in the list.  The environment variable shows it's looking in the same places for modules as a regular powershell window (including under my user folder, so it's running under my context).  The AD module shows under -ListAvailable in a regular powershell window.

I've tried modifying the import-module command to address the actual AD module as directly as possible, and I cannot get it to load.

Can anyone think of a way to get the AD module to show up to a powershell session launched from a VB macro in Excel 2007?

Comment: This one *may* be more quickly addressed at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier if you go 
.bat -> .ps1
Making a bat file to call the powershell should be easy for someone used to working with vba & powershell.

Make the .bat work with the powershell. Figuring out what it takes for the .bat to work may be enough to show it what needs to change in the vba code, otherwise just use the .bat in the vba and all should be good.